# KeyError - Unable to resolve #python

Tags: python-3.x, keyerror

Written the below code as a placeholder to capture data from API:

```
paras = {'email': [],
        'status': [],
        'firstName': [],
        'lastName': [],
        'position': []
        }

companyname = []
fullname = []
website = []

for company in companies:
    info = get_domain_search(company)
    if 'error' in info.keys():
        token = get_access_token()['access_token']
        info = get_domain_search(company)

    elif 'errors' in info.keys():
        continue

    k = 0
    for key in info['email']:
        for role in roles:
            if 'position' in key.keys():
                if role in key['position']:
                    for para in paras.keys():
                        if para in key.keys():
                            paras[para].append(key[para])
                        else:
                            paras[para].append('#N/A')
                    companyname.append(info['companyName'])
                    website.append(company)
                    if paras['firstName'][-1] + paras['lastName'][-1] == 'NANA':
                        fullname.append('#N/A')
                    else:
                        fullname.append(paras['firstName'][-1] + ' ' + paras['lastName'][-1])
                    k = 1

                else:
                    pass
            else:
                pass
```

encounter below error:

> ---> 23     for key in info['email']:
>
> KeyError: 'email'

Not sure if my for loop is the cause

Comment: Junmai, do the **info** variable contain the key **email**. Try dumping the *info* variable and check the email key exists. If it exists check whether it is an object or array.

Also please add the programming language tag in the question.

Comment: What is your py version?

Comment: @Tsakiroglou Fotis  3.7.4

Comment: @Junmai Working for me. What happens if you try to remove empty [] ?